# Getting the best of static_assert and std::is_invocable

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, static-assert

I have a library with several function objects that might only accept a few types depending on [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral). I want [`std::is_invocable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) to return `false` when the condition fails, but I also want a nice `static_assert` error message when a user tries to call an instance of the function object. Here is a simplified example of the function objects I currently have:

```
struct function
{
    template<typename Iterator>
    auto operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) const
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
        >>
    { /* something */ }
};
```

With such an implementation, `std::is_invocable` is `std::false_type` as expected when the SFINAE condition is not met, but users encounter ugly SFINAE error messages when they try to call the function object with parameters that don't meet the SFINAE condition.

To get better error messages, I tried the following solution instead:

```
struct function
{
    template<typename Iterator>
    auto operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) const
        -> void
    {
        static_assert(std::is_integral_v<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>,
                      "function can only be called with a collection of integers");

        /* something */
    }
};
```

With this implementation, users get friendly error messages when the original SFINAE condition is not met, but `std::is_invocable` is `std::true_type` when asked whether a `function` instance can handle a type that does not satisfy `std::is_integral`.

I tried several tricks and variations involving `decltype(auto)`, `if constexpr` and other mechanisms, but couldn't get a class where error messages were nice and where `std::is_invocable` corresponded to the expected `std::false_type` when asking whether `function` could be invoked with incorrect types.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to get both proper `std::is_invocable` *and* user-friendly error messages?

Comment: I just recently wrote a blog post about this: https://gracicot.github.io/tricks/2017/07/01/deleted-function-diagnostic.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one awful way. Add an overload:

```
template <typename Iterator>
auto operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) const
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<
        typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
    >>;

template <typename Iterator, class... Args>
void operator()(Iterator, Iterator, Args&&... ) const = delete; // must be integral
```

This satisfies the `is_invocable<>` condition, since the contrained function template is more specialized and preferred - so if the condition is met, the function is invocable, else it's deleted.

This does a little bit better on the error case, since if you try to call it, you get:

```
foo.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cxx:31:13: error: use of deleted function ‘void function::operator()(Iterator, Iterator, Args&& ...) const [with Iterator = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*; Args = {}]’
     f(&i, &i);
             ^
foo.cxx:19:10: note: declared here
     void operator()(Iterator, Iterator, Args&&... ) const = delete; // must be integral
          ^~~~~~~~
```

The comment shows up in the error message, which is sort of like a static assert message?

---

This is actually one of the motivations for Concepts. With a `requires` instead of an `enable_if`, we get:

```
foo.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cxx:26:13: error: no match for call to ‘(function) (std::__cxx11::string*, std::__cxx11::string*)’
     f(&i, &i);
             ^
foo.cxx:11:10: note: candidate: void function::operator()(Iterator, Iterator) const requires  is_integral_v<typename std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type> [with Iterator = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*]
     void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) const
          ^~~~~~~~
foo.cxx:11:10: note:   constraints not satisfied
foo.cxx:11:10: note: ‘is_integral_v<typename std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type>’ evaluated to false
```

That's... a little better I guess.

Comment: The concepts solutions is indeed a bit better. There are other places when I need the SFINAE behaviour, I'd need to check whether the `= delete` is viable in my case, but that may be an interesting path to explore.

Comment: I found [an article](https://gracicot.github.io/tricks/2017/07/01/deleted-function-diagnostic.html) that improves upon the `= delete` trick, allowing to provide a dedicated `static_assert` message, which is not bad.

Comment: @Morwenn I wonder if author of the article is right... I read you **cannot** create template that won't have any valid specialization and `static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T,T>, "message")` would break that rule making the code ill-formed without even diagnostic reqired.

Comment: @W.F. Sure you can. `template <class T> inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;` Hypothetically, somebody somewhere *could* specialize that to be `true`, so it can't be ill-formed to say `static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "message");`

Comment: @Barry So you're saying until no one will specialize it, it is ill-formed? I've came across interpretation (I think by Columbo) that it is illegal either way...